# KeyDown event not triggered for TextBox when setting IME as Japanese?

Tags: uwp, textbox, ime

I have TextBox and I need to customize KeyDown event. But it is not triggered when setting IME as Japanese. It is working fine when using IME as English.

Also, I have added Japanese in my System Languages. And I changed IME to Japanese. Do I need to change any other settings in my system level?

Regards,
Shobika.

Answer (score 1):

> I have TextBox and I need to customize KeyDown event. But it is not triggered when setting IME as Japanese. It is working fine when using IME as English.

It is by design, enable the [Input Method Editor (IME)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh967427(v=win.10)) and Text Services Framework (TSF) when your apps have users who require assistive technology to enter text in complex languages, like Japanese and Simplified Chinese. Apps do not receive this event when an **Input Method Editor (IME)** is enabled. The Input Method Editor (IME) [**handles all keyboard input**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.corewindow.keydown) and sets Handled to true.